# Android Studio auto-updating app.iml support libs to 'alpha' versions

Tags: android, android-studio

Why is Android Studio 1.5.1 (stable) auto-updating my `app.iml` file to use alpha support libraries?

[image]

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/8tory/parse-android-sdk.m2/raw/master/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1'
}
```

Comment: Please post your module's `build.gradle` file, or at least where you are defining `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: @CommonsWare added

Comment: @CommonsWare after I changed the support lib versions from `22.1` to `22.2.1` in my `build.gradle`, the `app.iml` file updated the versions to `22.2.1`. So maybe it has something to do with not choosing the latest version or something? Then AS defaults to most recent alpha?

Comment: It shouldn't. That's the whole point of specifying older editions: for reproducible builds. You're certainly not getting those libraries due to requesting the N Developer Preview in `build.gradle`, so that's not it.